# Why is UIBarButtonItem(title:image:primaryAction:menu:) not available in Mac Catalyst?

Tags: ios, uikit, mac-catalyst

I'm trying to invoke UIBarButtonItem(title:image:primaryAction:menu:) -- which worked just fine with iOS and iPadOS. However, when invoking Mac Catalyst, the compiler is complaining about this statement:

UIBarButtonItem(title: "Files", image: nil, primaryAction: nil, menu: leftItems)

saying that it "Cannot convert value of type 'UIMenu' to expected argument type 'Selector?'.

There's another form of UIBarButtonItem's initializer that does want a selector -- and I'm using that elsewhere -- but the documentation states that this initializer *is* available for Mac Catalyst.

What's going on?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>That must be a bug with Xcode as</del> the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/3600776-init) clearly states the initializer is available for Mac Catalyst too.

[image]

---

**Update:**
I think you're using Xcode on macOS 10.15 or the macOS target is 10.15.

[image]

In this case, it's expected to see the compiler error. You need to change the target to macOS 11, and that's not possible on macOS Catalina.

So, I guess you have to try that on macOS 11 Beta, or wait until it's released.